# DOMS and other Side Effects from Bicycling

Tags: bicycling, muscle-soreness, doms

Am I right that Bicycling causes less DOMS, soreness and similar negative side-effects than other forms of cardio exercise?  (For similar cardio results).

What are the main negative side effects of bicycling?  Conditions that  might cause problem when biking?

Comment: DOMS has nothing to do with the type of exercise. DOMS can be a result of any type of exercise, and has to do more with effort and duration than anything else.

Comment: You can get plenty sore on a bike (at least the first time you hop on), depending on volume and intensity.  DOMS, while it is linked to eccentric load and metabolic stress (as mentioned), is also linked to novelty, specifically, soreness caused by neurological "growth".  Do ANY new movement pattern long and hard enough, and you'll be feeling it the next couple days.

Answer (score 1):

DOMS is caused eccentric movements that you have not properly worked up to, which cycling has none of. Running could give you DOMS in your calves if you are sedentary, or if you try minimalist shoes without working up to it, but generally cardio is not going to feature much eccentric movement and people would rarely get DOMS from any endurance work. However, that doesn't mean you can't get normal soreness if you increase time or intensity too quickly.

Improper form while cycling, such as your knees not being aligned, could cause tendonitis. On a racing style bike, the crouch position can cause lower back pain. Saddle sores are a concern for longer rides. The biggest danger, by far, is cars.